# Calculate Each Weekday Dates

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, date, datetime

Alright, so I have the following code to grab the last 4 characters in a folder name, which will always be date, formatted as MMDD. This date will always be a Monday date as well.

Folder name example being trimmed below: C:\Temp\Textfiles\20120813

```
Dim MMDD_Date As String = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(TextBox1_Path.Text, 4)
```

What I'm unsure of, is how to calculate the remaining days for that week, ending on a Friday. Obvioulsy you cant convert the string to an int and add 1 since some months have 29, 30 or 31 depending on leap years.

The end result would be something like this:

> Mon: 0813
>
> Tue: 0814
>
> Wed: 0815
>
> Thu: 0816
>
> Fri: 0817

Any suggestions to point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you have the 'year' (YYYY) component?

Comment: Yes, the year component is part of the folder name. Folder name example: C:\Temp\Textfiles\20120813

Comment: Is this your case? Please help me understand. If the folder name ends with '0814' (Tue), you want a list of strings from '0814' (Tue) to '0817' (Fri). If the folder name ends with '0817' (Fri), you want just that. If the folder name is Sat or Sun, its a no-op.

Comment: No, the folder will always end in the Monday date of each week. I need to calculate the rest of the week and only return MMDD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want something like this. I am not entirely sure. This is in C#, I assume you can convert it to VB.NET.

```
var folderName = @"C:\Temp\Textfiles\20120813"; //Test input
var dateString = folderName.Substring(folderName.Length - 8);
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var counter = date.DayOfWeek; //OP says this is always a Monday, but is not hardcoded
var mmdd = int.Parse(folderName.Substring(folderName.Length - 4));
var myDates = new List<string>();

do
{
  myDates.Add(string.Format("{0}: {1:0000}", counter.ToString().Substring(0, 3), mmdd++)); //E.g. "Mon: 0813"
} while (counter++ < DayOfWeek.Friday);
```

Comment: Yeah I'll give it a try, not familiar with c# though. Thanks.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Took some of your code and the other posters code and combined? Well it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Create DateTime using year, month and day. Use that created date to easily get subsequent days.

```
   ' Parse Y, M and D (Integers) from folder name
   ' ...

    Dim X As DateTime
    X = New DateTime(Y, M, D) 

    Dim Tue As String = X.AddDays(1).ToString("MMDD")
    Dim Wen As String = X.AddDays(2).ToString("MMDD")
    Dim Thr As String = X.AddDays(3).ToString("MMDD")
    Dim Fri As String = X.AddDays(4).ToString("MMDD")
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, well here's what I came up with. Took suggestions from @channs and @Dusan and combined the efforts.

```
    Dim FolderDate As String = TextBox1_Path.Text
    Dim DateString = FolderDate.Substring(FolderDate.Length - 8)
    Dim d = DateTime.ParseExact(DateString, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

    Dim Mon As String = d.ToString("MMdd")
    Dim Tue As String = d.AddDays(1).ToString("MMdd")
    Dim Wed As String = d.AddDays(2).ToString("MMdd")
    Dim Thu As String = d.AddDays(3).ToString("MMdd")
    Dim Fri As String = d.AddDays(4).ToString("MMdd")

    'test output
    MsgBox(Mon)
    MsgBox(Tue)
    MsgBox(Wed)
    MsgBox(Thu)
    MsgBox(Fri)
```